# unityscript Function. Object does not support slicing Error

Tags: function, object, unity-game-engine, type-conversion, unityscript

I'm writing a very simple function where I am supposed to find the distance between two 3 d points. One set of points are given directly as floats, whereas the others are given as a horizontal array.

The three inputs are x,y,z which are the floats and a row pickups[0] being passed as par which is ["blue1",441.2223, 231.44, 127.7466]
Now, the row comes up as an object of course. I was having a problem with making a function to calculate the distance: My code as of now is:\

```
function distance(x,y,z,par)
{
var p:float;
p=Mathf.Sqrt( (x-parseFloat(par[1].ToString())) * (x-parseFloat(par[1].ToString())) +          (y-parseFloat(par[2].ToString())) * (y-parseFloat(par[2].ToString())) + (z-parseFloat(par[3].ToString())) * (z-parseFloat(par[3].ToString())));
return p;
}
```

Please try and help me out.

Comment: Are you sure this is JavaScript? I haven't seen `Mathf` and `var p:float` before.

Comment: It's unity Javascript... It's not my Homework :) .. I just started using this and am getting a weird error... lol Yeah I can understand now why you would guess that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error has to do with `var p:float;`, you don't need to try and predeclare the variable p as anything as javascript is type-less. What the reference is refering to with `static function Sqrt (f : float) : float` is that it is expecting a variable that is a float and returns a float. Your code should be written as:

```
function distance(x,y,z,par)
{
   var p = Mathf.Sqrt( (x-parseFloat(par[1])) * (x-parseFloat(par[1])) + (y-parseFloat(par[2])) * (y-parseFloat(par[2])) + (z-parseFloat(par[3])) * (z-parseFloat(par[3])));
   return p;
}
```

You also don't need toString() your parameters as they will be parsed into a float.